# Error linking to a servlet from an image tag

Tags: java, html, servlets

I am using eclipse and java ee, a tomcat server, and I cant seem to be able to run a servlet from inside an image tag. Everything is run from my laptop. All my other servlets work.

In my html, I have this line

```
<img src="images/test.jpg">
```

In my web.xml, I have this mapping.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.myImageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In myImageServlet doGet() I have this.

```
System.out.println("WORK!");
```

WORK! never gets printed out.
Any Ideas? 
Thank you for the help.

EDIT:
If I go in developer tools and check network, the request sent out is this.

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/RotoMonkey/images/test.jpg
```

What is returned is a 404, Requested resource unavailable.

I have tried changing the encoding of my web.xml to UTF-8
Nothing changed.

Comment: src is an attribute of img

Comment: edited, sorry. I made a mistake writing my question.

Comment: What does the browser retrieve instead? Press F12 in Chrome/IE/Firebug to see the HTTP traffic monitor in Network section. Perhaps it's just a 404 which is rather self-explaining.

Comment: You need to elaborate the problem in developer's terms, not in enduser's terms. Now, what does the browser retrieve instead?

Comment: It says The requested resource is not available. Status 404

Comment: What is the context of your application?

Comment: The context is that I open a web page and want to show all the profile pictures saved in my database. In my database I have the path to the image which is located on my hard drive. Basically, I open the web page, images are displayed. There are a bunch of tutorials on how to do this, but I can't seem to get the servlet to run....